# How can I prevent VS Code from changing files that do not belong to the workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Assume I am working on a project folder `my_project` while using `Python`. I want to make sure, `VS Code` does not allow me to change files that do not belong to the project (they are outside `my_project` folder).

Example scenario: Once I was debugging a code in Python, I ended up in a file that belonged to my virtual environment and by mistake I pressed a key somewhere. This caused everything crashes afterward and was hard to catch (note it does not show in `git status`). If I would do the same thing on `PyCharm` it would show a pop up window warning me. Is the same thing possible for `VS Code`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note: VS Code 1.86 has a feature to disable *autosaving* files outside the current workspace via the setting `files.autoSaveWorkspaceFilesOnly`. See issue ticket [Disable autosave or save outside project folder
#160651](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160651).

---

As for preventing *yourself* from making such modifications via VS Code, I've come up with a partial workaround that isn't perfect:

```json
"files.readonlyInclude": {
   "**/*": true,
},
"files.readonlyExclude": {
   "/**/name-of-your-workspace-folder/**/*": true,
},
```

You could put that in your workspace [.vscode/settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

Drawbacks of the approach:

- You have to assume that the workspace folder has a specific name. For things like git repos where usually people just accept the default name, this may be fine, but some people like to give their git repo checkouts custom root directory names, in which case they'd need to edit the settings.
- It assumes that no other directory else in the entire filesystem will have the same name as the workspace folder. That might be a fine assumption for projects with rather exotic names, but that won't always hold true.
- The readonly editor feature only affects the editor. It will not prevent any programs you are debugging from editing files that are outside of the workspace folder.

If variable substitution in VS Code settings.json was a thing, then you wouldn't have the first two listed problems above, and could instead write something like this:

```json
"files.readonlyInclude": {
   "**/*": true,
},
"files.readonlyExclude": {
   "${workspaceFolder}/**/*": true,
   // "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/specific/subfolder/**/*": true,
},
```

But alas, [it doesn't seem like variable substitution is supported in settings.json- at least for these two settings properties](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184698#issuecomment-1612636141).

---

There's a related feature-request issue ticket at [Add option to mark any file outside current workspace read-only #184698](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184698), which is closed for not receiving enough community support in the allotted time window. You could try raising it again if you really want it and the workaround isn't satisfactory for you. Or, take a look at the extension [`ArturoDent.read-only-non-workspace`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.read-only-non-workspace) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>. Note that the third disclaimer listed above still applies to this.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is this extension that I wrote, [Read-only: Non-workspaceFiles](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.read-only-non-workspace).

It will automatically set any file that is not from the current workspace (works in multiroot workspaces too) to `read-only` for that session.  It doesn't change the file's underlying read/write permissions.

If you try to write to a file that is session read-only, a pop-up will appear to unset it.

[image: set non-workspace file to read-only]

Comment: this only prevents the user from editing the file, correct? it will not prevent other programs or extensions from writing to the file?

Comment: @starball It is session-only, not a change to the OS file permissions so yes, other programs can edit the file (and vscode watches for those changes automatically and updates the marked file).  In the vscode window where a file is marked as read-only by this extension, other extensions cannot make an edit (they can make selections) to the marked file.  If the file is open in another vscode window - where it is not marked as read-only - changes can be made in that other instance.